# Extract Maximum and minimum value using awk

Tags: shell, unix, awk

How to find maximum and minimum value from the below table using `awk` command.

```
20 90 60 30
55 75 80 85
10 15 99 95
55 95 70 20
9  35 85 75
```

I want the output like max `value=99` and `min=9`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**with** gnu awk:

```
awk '{for(x=1;x<=NF;x++)a[++y]=$x}END{c=asort(a);print "min:",a[1];print "max:",a[c]}'
```

output:

```
min: 9
max: 99
```

**without** awk:

```
xargs -n1|sort -n|head or tail -1
```

e.g.

min:

```
kent$  echo "20 90 60 30
55 75 80 85
10 15 99 95
55 95 70 20
9  35 85 75"|xargs -n1|sort -n|head -1
9
```

max:

```
kent$  echo "20 90 60 30
55 75 80 85
10 15 99 95
55 95 70 20
9  35 85 75"|xargs -n1|sort -n|tail -1
99
```

you can of course `xargs -n1|sort -n` then pipe to awk to pick first and last and print in one shot.

Answer (score 4):

```
awk '
NR == 1 { min=max=$1 }
{
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        min = (min < $i ? min : $i)
        max = (max > $i ? max : $i)
    }
}
END {
    printf "min value = %s\n", (min == "" ? "NaN" : min)
    printf "max value = %s\n", (max == "" ? "NaN" : max)
}
' file
```

The test resulting in "NaN" is to accommodate empty input files.

Answer (score 4):

If you have `GNU awk`:

```
# using array
awk '{x[NR]=$1}END{asort(x);print "max="x[NR],"min="x[1]}' RS=' +|\n' file
max=99 min=9

# No array
awk 'NR==1{m=n=$1}{$1>m?m=$1:m;$1<n?n=$1:n}END{print "max="m,"min="n}' RS=' +|\n' file
max=99 min=9
```