# Need to find the max value in an array?

Tags: bash, awk, gawk

I'm new to awk programming.. after a long time I solved the 
min value using

```
echo ${GfieldList[@]} | tr ' ' '\n' | awk 'NR==1{min=$0}NR>1 && $1<min{min=$1;pos=NR}END{print "MinValue: " min}'
```

Need to find the MAX value? Can you please help me in this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17616597/extract-maximum-and-minimum-value-using-awk

Comment: Your questions are very similar. Can you extrapolate from the advice you've already been given?

Comment: Thanks glenn jacjman!